# SEO Friendly URL's Through -> modrewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am attempting SEO friendly-ize my URL's.

Sample URL (that I would like):

> http://sampleurl.com/FILENAME/VARIABLE/

What I would like to transpose this to is:

> http://sampleurl.com/FILENAME.php?x=VARIABLE

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ $1.php?l=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# Proper regex -> ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)
</IfModule>
```

My challenges are:

1) The trailing slashes:  with my regex I have to have a trailing slash.  When I change the regex to read `^(.*)/(.*)/?$` - It adds a ".php" to the end of the variable. And, if I leave the `?` off - the trailing slash is required - or, it resolves to the "index.php" result

2) Same in the second RewriteRule - with the `?` before the slash = Internal Server Error - without the `?` = all good.

So everything works now, except I must have that trailing slash.

Seems like I am missing something pretty easy here - and would appreciate someone pointing it out.

Comment: Do you get the same result with `^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` and for the 2nd rule `^([^/]+)/?$`?